# Convert an MP4 to WAV file using Azure media-services transforms

Tags: c#, azure, azure-media-services

We have a blob storage that we are putting MP4 files into.  We want to create a function that watches for the incoming files (like a pub/sub), and then using azure media-services encode the file to a wav, and save the transformed artifact to another blob storage container.  I can create the job to watch for the files that come in, the problem we are having is finding out how to create a wav file using the media-services transforms. We are trying to avoid having to copy the MP4 files to another location to encode them to wav files, then deleting the MP4 file and the wav file once we are done.  These files can run into the gig size quite a bit.

We use the wav files to transcribe them into text (our transcription software requires the files in wav format).  We looked at the azure speech services to do the transcriptions, but it is cost prohibitive, and the transcription software we currently use is specialized for our line of work and more efficient at transcriptions.

I guess the first question is "Is it possible to transform an MP4 to wav using azure media-services?"  If so, does someone have an example on how this is done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample of an Azure function that can encode a Azure blob and output to a blob blob. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet-core-functions-integration/tree/master/Encoding

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, you can't create a Transform in our service today that will enable you to decode an MP4 input file into a WAV output file.

Where are you running your transcription software? Have you considered running open source SW like ffmpeg on those compute instances to convert MP4 to WAV?

Thanks

Comment: We are looking at running FFMpeg to do the transcription.  We were hoping to avoid downloading the file to do the transform and hoping it could be done in azure.   We have a micoservice that will be running to move the wav file to the transcription service, so we can modify it to use FFMpeg to do the transform first.  Thanks.

Comment: Presume you know that you can write that microservice using Azure Functions? With an App Service plan, I am told that you can have long running Functions (default timeout of 30min which can be extended further). Thanks